# InvalidOperationException: The relative page path 'index' can only be used while executing a Razor Page. Specify a root relative path with a leading

Tags: asp.net-core

InvalidOperationException: The relative page path 'index' can only be used while executing a Razor Page. Specify a root relative path with a leading '/' to generate a URL outside of a Razor Page. If you are using LinkGenerator then you must provide the current HttpContext to use relative pages.

Comment: Could you share some code to reproduce  your problem ?